# How to get product Frontend URL in Admin in Magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, product, url

I am using below code to get Product frontend URL in admin but it's throwing 404 error.

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
$product->getProductUrl()
```

Can anyone tell me how to get product frontend URL in admin. I want to get rewrite URL so that if I click on link then it will redirect to  product view page in frontend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$storeId = 1;
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId($storeId)->load($productId);
$url = $product->getProductUrl();
```

just replace `1` with your store id.

Comment: You never actually use the `$storeId` variable.  Shouldn't it be

`$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId($storeId)->load($productId);`

Comment: right. thanks for spotting this.